# Swift - Regular Expression match anything in quotes

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am looking for a regular expression that matches anything inside the quotes:

> = "d";

Currently I have this:

> [^=\s"].*[^";]

Which works for everything

> = "Something rather long";

until I get to a single character situation as mentioned with the single d line. I am not well versed in regular expressions, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And can there be escape sequences inside? Like `= "d \"s\""`? What is the code you are using with the regex? Maybe `(?<=").+?(?=";)` will do.

Comment: anything can be inside the quotes, escaped characters too.

Comment: I think you need `let rx = "\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"";`

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
"([^"]|(?<=\)")*"
```

includes escaped `"` inside quotes.

Comment: your last one you posted seemed to work just fine: "([^"]|(?<=\\)")*", but this one you just updated to now throws an error...

Comment: It depends on how you use it. In some forms you need to escape some characters to get their literal. If the first one suits you it is alright.